# Parallel section numberings in ConTeXt

Tags: sectioning, context

Is there a way to define parallel section numberings for different section-like entities, e.g.:

```
\startsectionA[title = {secA1}]
\stopsectionA
\startsectionB[title = {secB1}]
\stopsectionB
\startsectionA[title = {secA2}]
\stopsectionA
\startsectionA[title = {secA3}]
\stopsectionA
etc.
```

Which should then turn out as

```
1. secA1
I. secB1
2. secA2
3. secA3
etc.
```

These titles should appear in the TOC and in the headers.

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail on "why" you want this. There are essentially three ways to do this: (i) manually keep track of your own section numbers like the solution by Henri Menke below; (ii) Hijack a lower section level (say `\subsubsubsubsection` `:-)`)  and make sure that it does not reset with the higher levels; (iii) use enumerations (which are typically used for theorems etc.).

Comment: @Aditya Essentially, what I need here are numbered theorems, definitions, so (iii) enumerations, seem to be the right choice, except for I need them to appear in the TOC alongside with parts, chapters, etc., and appear in the headers, and they seem to do neither in a straightforward way (at least, it's not in ConTeXt wiki, but, hopefully, I'm missing something). (ii) hijacking lower section levels sounds like quite robust solution, but not very elegant. (i) If it doesn't have ugly side effects, it seems to solve my problem.

Comment: OT: In ConTeXt keys are sensitive to what space; so `title = ...` will not work while `title=...` will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overload the sectioning command and keep track using your own counters.  I don't think this is a good idea at all.

```
\unprotect

\definecounter[sectionA][way=bychapter]
\define\startsectionA{\dodoubleempty\start_section_A}
\define\stopsectionA{\stopsection}
\def\start_section_A[#1][#2]{%
  \incrementcounter[sectionA]%
  \startsection[ownnumber={\directconvertedcounter{sectionA}\empty},
    incrementnumber=no,#1][#2]}

\definecounter[sectionB][way=bychapter,numberconversion=R]
\define\startsectionB{\dodoubleempty\start_section_B}
\define\stopsectionB{\stopsection}
\def\start_section_B[#1][#2]{%
  \incrementcounter[sectionB]%
  \startsection[ownnumber={\directconvertedcounter{sectionB}\empty},
    incrementnumber=no,#1][#2]}

\protect

\starttext

\placecontent

\startsection[title={Normal Section}]
  normal section
\stopsection

\startsectionA[title={Section A}]
  section A
\stopsectionA

\startsectionB[title={Section B}]
  section B
\stopsectionB

\startsectionA[title={Section A}]
  section A
\stopsection

\startsection[title={Normal Section}]
  normal section
\stopsection

\startsectionA[title={Section A}]
  section A
\stopsection

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: You could use the counter mechanism (`\definecounter`, `\incrementcounter` and set `conversion=...`) to automate manual conversion. (You also get automatic resets for free (`way=bychapter`, etc.)

Comment: @Aditya Thanks a lot!  Your comments are invaluable.

Comment: @Aditya There is no need for a extra counter because you can get (and convert) the value of another section with the `\namedheadnumber` command, e.g. `ownnumber=\convertnumber{R}{\namedheadnumber{sectionA}}`.

Comment: @Metafox That does not work as expected ([Code](http://hastebin.com/kevenunide.tex), [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8gnAw.png)).

Comment: @HenriMenke You have to use the take the value from `sectionA` or in your example from `section`. With a small change in the core you can even put the whole thing in a `\setups` command without the need for custom commands.

Comment: @Metafox Could you please make this an answer?  I'm very interested in how you would work this out.

Comment: @HenriMenke I can send a diff to the ConTeXt list because changes in the core aren’t fitted for an answer. The [setup](http://hastebin.com/emakikakoy.tex) for the counter can be applied with the `\setupstructure` command which isn’t possible at the moment.

Comment: @Metafox: The way I understood the question, `sectionA` and `sectionB` can be interleaved in an arbitrary manner. So, the number of `sectionB` need not be the same as that of `sectionA`

Answer (score 3):

In the comments you say that you want theorems but you want them to appear in TOC. Each enumeration is stored in a list and you can simply display combined lists in TOCs. Here is an example where `sectionA` is a regular section and `sectionB` is an enumeration. I modified the layout of enumerations so that it typesets like a section.

```
\definehead[sectionA][section]
\defineenumeration[sectionB][title=yes, text=, headstyle=\tfa, titlestyle=\tfa, titleleft=, titleright=, numberconversion=R]

\starttext

\placelist[sectionA, sectionB]

\startsectionA[title={First Section A}]
  section A
  \getmarking[sectionA]
\stopsectionA

\startsectionB[title={First Section B}]
  section B
\stopsectionB

\startsectionA[title={Second Section A}]
  section A
\stopsectionA

\startsectionA[title={Third Section A}]
  section A
\stopsectionA

\startsectionB[title={Second Section B}]
  section B
\stopsectionB

\stoptext
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Looks cool. Now i see how to make TOC with enumerations in it, but how to make enumeration titles appear in the headers?